# Font face not doing nothing how does it work?

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face

I have this website template at http://oarvoredo.businesscatalyst.com/
and the font face is not working on I.E..

What am I doing wrong?

```
    @font-face {
        font-family:"ERASLGHT fonte";
        src: url(/fontes/ERASLGHT.otf),
        url(/fontes/ERASLGHT.woff),
        url(/fontes/ERASLGHT.svg),
        url(/fontes/ERASLGHT.TTF),
        url(/fontes/ERASLGHT.eot);
    }
```

Comment: "Not doing nothing" so it is doing something? Well if you tried everything there is nothing we can help you with then... So let's try again. What version of IE and please list everything you tried.

Comment: so it is doing something?

Comment: remove the quotes that wrapping your code, then try again.

Comment: it renders on the other browsers but on IE it does not.

Comment: i removed the quotes from the post.ok